# I am getting a "Run-time error '424': Object Required" on a data entry form

Tags: vba, ms-access, runtime-error

This data entry form has a search box at the top where I have included some code in the OnCurrent and BeforeInsert events of the form to react to what happens in the search box.

In the AfterInsert event:

```
Private Sub Form_AfterInsert()
 
    Records.MoveLast
    TotalRecords = Records.RecordCount
    Exit Sub

End Sub
```

When I enter in a new record and tab out of the last field I get the Run-time 424 error and after hitting debug it takes me to this code.  Any advice on how to fix this?

I tried putting in a error handler but the problem still persists.

Comment: Is MoveLast line triggering error? Or is code not even getting to that point? Not source of error but Exit Sub line is not needed. Also, should declare all variables. Is TotalRecords a field or a variable? If it is a field, why would you save this to table? I have never used AfterInsert or BeforeInsert. Possibly should be using BeforeUpdate or AfterUpdate.

Comment: `Records` is not a part of the Access object model. This is the "required object". You may be looking for `Me.RecordSet`.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying the issue!  got it fixed

Answer (score 0):

It is the `RecordsetClone` to use:

```vb
Private Sub Form_AfterInsert()

    Dim Records As DAO.Recordset

    Set Records = Me.RecordsetClone

    Records.MoveLast
    TotalRecords = Records.RecordCount
    Records.Close

End Sub
```